# Unable to load logged in User's Profile Image in Django template

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

This is my frontend code of header.html where I am typing to display the currently logged-in user's profile picture after the user authenticates. It works when my current user is on the home page or its profile but as soon as it moves to another's profile it starts displaying that profile's picture. I want to make it such like where ever logged in user move he/she should always see their profile picture

```
    <div><b><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Bondly</a></b></div>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div>
-------> <img src="{{user_profile.img_profile.url}}" />
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </header>
```

Here are code of my views.py

```
def profile(request, pf):
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=pf)
    user_profile = models.Profile.objects.get(usr=user_object)
    print(request.user.__doc__)
    posts = models.Post.objects.filter(user=pf)
    postsNum = len(posts)
    follor = request.user.username

    if models.Followers.objects.filter(follower=follor, user=pf).first():
        text = "Following"
    else:
        text = "Follow"

    followers = len(models.Followers.objects.filter(user=pf))
    following = len(models.Followers.objects.filter(follower=pf))

    context = {
        'user_object': user_object,
        "user_profile": user_profile,
        "posts": posts,
        'postsNum': postsNum,
        "text": text,
        "followers": followers,
        "following": following
        }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

and my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    """docstring for Profile."""
    usr: str = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_usr: int = models.IntegerField()
    Fname:str = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    Mname:str = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    Lname:str = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    Fhone:int = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    bio: str = models.TextField(blank=True)
    img_profile = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='ProfileIMG', default="blankprofile.png")
    location: str = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.usr.username
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use request.user to get logged in users data from your models in any template. The way you are currently loading user image is different, as it will load data of the user only when user data is passed in context for the template

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <div>
        <img src="{{ request.user.profile.img_profile.url }}" />
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am still not able to access current user's data, basically I am not able to reach { request.user.Profile }

Comment: Then you might need to double check if you have assigned any related name to your foreign key field in your Profile model. If you have then use that related_name instead of "profile" keyword in the template to load your profiles. But this is the way for loading profile data for logged in user without passing from backend functions

Comment: Also you need to use "profile" not "Profile" to access logged in users profile model data

Comment: Nahh! Not working even with 'p' and my foreign key is usr but I am still able to get logged in user's data.